# Transform a list of dictionaries to a dictionary of lists using the built-in dict commands

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
set personA {name Alice age 35}
set personB {name Bob age 42}
set persons [list $personA $personB]
```

Now I want to "transpose" them to a single dictionary which contains lists instead:

```
set transposedPersons {name {Alice Bob} age {35 42}}
```

I can achieve this using the following piece of code:

```
set keys {name {} age {}}
set transposedPersons [dict map {k _} $keys {
    lmap person $persons {dict get $person $k}
}]
```

I don't fully understand what some of the built-in [`dict`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm) commands do, like for example `dict merge`, `dict update` and `dict with`. I want to know if I can use one of them to simplify this dictionary-list transposition.

Particularly: Can I somehow automatically use the keys `name` and `age` from the original dictionaries instead of having to write them out again?

(I am restricted to Tcl 8.5, but would still be interested in a solution that requires Tcl 8.6.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Tcl will automatically copy values behind the scenes as necessary so as to maintain an immutable view through each reference, you can actually do this:

```
# I prefer to use “-” as my ignored variable name, and not “_”. YMMV
set transposedPersons [dict map {k -} [lindex $persons 0] {
    lmap person $persons {dict get $person $k}
}]
```

It does assume that each dictionary in `$persons` has the same set of keys as the first one, but that's necessary for transposition to work as you've done it anyway. (Tcl does *not* have a NULL; it corresponds to an unset variable or an absent key.)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach person $persons {
    dict for {key val} $person {
        dict lappend transposedPersons $key $val
    }
}
```

What you want to do is to incrementally add values under each key to a dictionary named `transposedPersons`. The operation you need for that is `dict lappend transposedPersons $key $val`.

The keys and values are taken from the dictionaries describing persons. To iterate over the keys and corresponding values in one dictionary stored in the variable `person`, you can use `dict for {key val} $person { ... }`.

The dictionaries are elements in a list. To iterate over the person dictionaries, use `foreach person $persons { ... }`.

The `dict merge` command takes a number of dictionary values as arguments and creates a combined dictionary value containing all the keys in all those dictionaries. The value for each key is the value from the last dictionary to have that key. So

```
dict merge {a 1 d 9} {b 2 d 8} {c 3 d 7}
# -> a 1 d 7 b 2 c 3
```

The resulting dictionary gets a total of four keys from three different dictionaries, with the common key `d` getting the value 7 from the last dictionary. Note, though, that the key `d` is inserted between `a` and `b`, since the first occurrence of the key was after `a` but before `b`.

The `dict update` command takes a dictionary variable, a set of key-variable name mappings, and a script. Before the script is evaluated, a set of local variables are created, assigned new values, or unset depending on which keys are present in the dictionary variable given. If a variable named in the mapping already existed, its value will be overwritten by the value associated with the key if the key is present: if not, the variable is unset. If a variable didn't exist, it will be created if the corresponding key is present.

After the script is evaluated, each of these variables, if they exist, will have their value inserted into the dictionary under the corresponding key. If the variable is unset, the key is removed.

If you assume

```
set d {firstname Sally lastname Bowles balance 2000 address {Foo Street}}
set amt 150
set script {
    if {![info exists mn]} {set mn H}
    unset addr
    if {$amt > 0} {set bal [expr {$bal-$amt}]}
}
```

the following invocation

```
dict update d firstname fn middlename mn lastname ln balance bal address addr $script
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
set mappings {firstname fn middlename mn lastname ln balance bal address addr}
foreach {keyname varname} $mappings {
    if {[dict exists $d $keyname]} {
        set $varname [dict get $d $keyname]
    } else {
        unset -nocomplain $varname
    }
}
eval $script
foreach {keyname varname} $mappings {
    if {[info exists $varname]} {
        dict set d $keyname [set $varname]
    } else {
        dict unset d $keyname
    }
}
```

except that the helper variables (`keyname` etc) aren't created.

In both cases, the updated dictionary in `d` contains

```
firstname Sally lastname Bowles balance 1850 middlename H
```

i.e. a new key was created, another was deleted, and a third had its value changed because of what happened to the variables in the script.

The mapped-to variables continue to exist in the local scope after the command has been evaluated.

The `dict with` command is similar, but maps all keys in the dictionary to variables with the same names as the keys, and the command also allows a key chain to be specified to get a subdictionary of a dictionary. I'd give an example, but this answer is far too long already.

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm)